# How to work with telerik multi column combo box?

Tags: c#, winforms, telerik

I'm using a *telerik multi combo box* as a column in *telerik grid view*

i want to resize it and also
i want to get it's first multi combo box  column  and i don't know how to get that i tried a little bit

this is for resizing it which doesn't work

```
        GridViewMultiComboBoxColumn col = new GridViewMultiComboBoxColumn();

        RadMultiColumnComboBoxElement editor = (RadMultiColumnComboBoxElement)this.radGridView1.ActiveEditor;
        editor.AutoSizeDropDownToBestFit = true;

        editor.EditorControl.MasterTemplate.AutoGenerateColumns = false;
```

searched every where but they lead me no where can you teach me

thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 1):

To resize it, use this property:

```
radGridView1.Columns["YourMCCBColumnNBame"].Width = 100;
```

To get a reference to the column, use this collection:

```
GridViewMultiComboBoxColumn mccbCol = (GridViewMultiComboBoxColumn)radGridView1.Columns["YourMCCBColumnNBame"];
```

Answer (score 0):

Make an event of CellEditorInitialized in RadGridView.

```
 private void DGVPurchase_CellEditorInitialized(object sender, GridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Column is GridViewMultiComboBoxColumn)
        {
            RadMultiColumnComboBoxElement editor = e.ActiveEditor as RadMultiColumnComboBoxElement;
            editor.Columns["ShortName"].BestFit(); //Auto Widht
            editor.Columns["ID"].IsVisible = false; // Visiblity
            editor.Columns["Price"].Width = 120; //custom width
        }
    }
```